# How to format an external 64GB SD card (exfat) using command line?

Tags: command-line, exfat, micro-sd

I have an microSD card with 64GB capacity which has exFAT file system. If I insert it to my card reader, it is mounted automatically. But I am looking for a command to format the card. I installed **`exfat-fuse`** and **`exfat-utils`**, but could not find proper command to format my microSD card.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Straight from `apt-cache show exfat-utils` is the description:

```
Description-en: utilities to create, check, label and dump exFAT filesystem
 Utilities to manage extended file allocation table filesystem.
 This package provides tools to create, check and label the
 filesystem. It contains
  - dumpexfat to dump properties of the filesystem
  - exfatfsck / fsck.exfat to report errors found on a exFAT filesystem
  - exfatlabel to label a exFAT filesystem
  - mkexfatfs / mkfs.exfat to create a exFAT filesystem.
```

You would use `mkfs.exfat` to format the partition, the same as you would use `mkfs.fat` to format a normal FAT partition.

Answer (score 3):

open the terminal:

1/ type "man mkfs.exfat", to read how to use it.

2/ type "sudo fdisk -l", to determine where your sd card is mounted. example: /dev/sdc

3/ to format a 128gb SD card and give it the name of "sdxc128",

type "sudo mkfs.exfat -n sdxc128 /dev/sdc"